# Call different models's method while value of different model's changed - odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, computed-field

There are two models, one to keep master entity and other is transaction model.

> Master model contains unique records, combinations of product and
>   warehouses and First stock date on which date that product is in in 
>   stock in that warehouse. Everyday one cron runs and it will store
>   stock entry in that table, product - warehouse and period combination.

```
class parameter_view(models.Model):
    _name = "parameter.view"
    _description = "Reorder Parameter View"
    _order = "product_id, warehouse_id"

    @api.multi
    def _set_first_date(self):
        for rec in self:
            if not rec.first_stock_date:
                domain = [('warehouse_id','=',rec.warehouse_id.id),('product_id','=',rec.product_id.id), ('qty_available','>',0)]        
                stock = self.env['warehouse.product.daily.stock'].search(domain, order='stock_date', limit=1)
                if stock and stock.stock_date:
                    rec.first_stock_date = stock.stock_date

    first_stock_date = fields.Date(string="First on Stock Date")
    product_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='product.product', string='Product')
    warehouse_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='stock.warehouse', string='WH')
```

Transaction model.

```
class warehouse_product_daily_stock(models.Model):
    _name = 'warehouse.product.daily.stock'
    _order = 'stock_date desc, product_id, warehouse_id'        
    _description = "Daily Product Stock Warehouse Wise"

    stock_date = fields.Date('Date')
    period_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='reorder.account.period', string='Period')
    product_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='product.product', string='Product')
    warehouse_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='stock.warehouse', string='Warehouse')
    qty_available = fields.Float('Qty On Hand')
```

> **Problem:**
>
> In starting phase if the product is not in stock then the first on
>   stock date set to null but after few days if product available in
>   warehouse then the first on stock date will be set automatically. But
>   that's not done. How can we call function of different model while
>   value of other model's record has been updated.

How can I call method of parameter view while the record of daily stock view updated. Manually I know. But is there any automatic way to call interdependent object's method.